# Change logcat color in intellij ... BUG?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, logcat

I want to change logcat messages color to another. 
File > Settings > [IDE Settings] Editor > Color & Fonts > Android logcat

But, all options are disabled!

[image]

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own scheme with the Save As... button and then uncheck the box in the bottom of the red circle in your screenshot (inherit attribute from:)

Answer (score 1):

Extending 0xDEADCODE's answer, here are the colors based on Eclipse's ADT.

Editor > Colors & Fonts > Android Logcat > Info > [#21FF05]
Editor > Colors & Fonts > Android Logcat > Debug > [#00E8FB]
Editor > Colors & Fonts > Android Logcat > Warning > [#FF6C0C]
Editor > Colors & Fonts > Android Logcat > Error > [#FF040B]
Editor > Colors & Fonts > Android Logcat > Assert > [#E500FF]